# Does Git head pointer generally/usually points to the latest/last (end) commit of a branch?

Tags: git

If I understand correct, a Git head pointer generally/usually points to the latest/last (end) commit of a branch.

I know head can point other objects, such as:

1. A specific non-end commit of the branch.
2. A specific tag of a group of commits.

But my question reference only the **general** or **usual** usage of that term, hence I ask:

Does Git head pointer generally/usually points to the latest/last (end) commit of a branch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-head-in-git

Comment: Are you asking about HEAD, as in, **the** HEAD, of which there is only one in a git repository? Or are you asking about the head**s** in `.git/refs/heads`, of which there may be many and which can be listed with `git branch --list`?

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: in typical usage, your HEAD pointer will be pointing to the tip of the branch you currently have checked out.

Longer answer:

First some concepts and terminology here.

HEAD pointer -> a way that git refers to the commit you are working off of.  If you make changes and commit them, what is currently referenced by HEAD becomes the parent of your new commit.  Then HEAD gets updated to point to your new commit.  Think of it as where the next commit is going to attach to.

Tip -> a typical term for the last commit in a branch.  So when you do something like `git checkout master` (no commit hash), you will get set your HEAD pointer to (effectively) look at the last commit on master (called the tip).

Now that we have that out of the way ...

In most day to day usage of git, you are going to checkout branches, make changes, commit, repeat.  Thus in typical usage, HEAD will always point to the tip of your branch.  In my experience, very rarely (relative to other operations I'm doing) do you ever need to check out a branch at a specific tag or commit.  But it can happen.  And when you do, you get a "detached head."

Paraphrasing and taking some examples from the [git documentation on detached heads](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head):

Say you start out with this:

```
           HEAD (refers to branch 'master')
            |
            v
a---b---c  branch 'master' (refers to commit 'c')
    ^
    |
  tag 'v2.0' (refers to commit 'b')
```

So if you add a commit, it becomes the child of the current HEAD.  (Then the branch 'master' ref gets updated to point to the new commit and thus HEAD gets indirectly updated.)

```
               HEAD (refers to branch 'master')
                |
                v
a---b---c---d  branch 'master' (refers to commit 'd')
    ^
    |
  tag 'v2.0' (refers to commit 'b')
```

But say you need to go back and look at something in the v2.0 release.  So you might do `git checkout v2.0`.  Then your state looks like this:

```
   HEAD (refers to commit 'b')
    |
    v
a---b---c---d  branch 'master' (refers to commit 'd')
    ^
    |
  tag 'v2.0' (refers to commit 'b')
```

Which means that your HEAD is no longer pointing to the tip of the branch.  If you were to forget where you were and added a commit here (and forgot to branch, shame on you), now you end up here:

```
     HEAD (refers to commit 'e')
      |
      v
      e
     /
a---b---c---d  branch 'master' (refers to commit 'd')
    ^
    |
  tag 'v2.0' (refers to commit 'b')
```

Now commit `e` is on something like a branch and is referred to by HEAD, making it the parent of your next commit.  This can become problematic if you move your HEAD by doing another checkout (of say, master).  Then you get to something like this:

```
               HEAD (refers to branch 'master')
      e---f     |
     /          v
a---b---c---d  branch 'master' (refers to commit 'd')
    ^
    |
  tag 'v2.0' (refers to commit 'b')
```

Without HEAD pointing to `f`, it's off in la-la-land all by itself with no real way to get to or reference it (you can get to it with the reflog if you really need it).  And any thing like `e` and `f` that don't have a ref could (and will) be pruned next time git does garbage collection, meaning that some work could just poof out of existence if you aren't careful.  Thankfully this can be remedied if you fix it before the garbage collector eats it (not going to detail that here).

The point of the long answer here is two-fold.  First is that, under most circumstances HEAD = tip of your branch.  Second is that, despite some other answers, HEAD does not necessarily need to be the tip of your branch (and can cause problems if you aren't careful).

Answer (score 0):

Not "generally", but **always** (SIC!!!)

### The HEAD - last commit snapshot, next parent

> The HEAD in Git is the pointer to the current branch reference, which
>   is in turn a pointer to the last commit you made or the last commit
>   that was checked out into your working directory. That also means it
>   will be the parent of the next commit you do. It's generally simplest
>   to think of it as HEAD is the snapshot of your last commit.

(c) [Reset Demystified](https://git-scm.com/blog)